# Вычисление в базе или в приложении?

Tags: php, база-данных, postgresql, производительность

Возник вопрос, возможно, глупый, но все же. Есть приложение на php и бд с субд Postgresql с расширением postgis. Допустим в бд хранятся координаты точек и нужно вычислить расстояние между двумя точками. Где лучше делать данное вычисление расстояния с точки зрения производительности, на уровне приложения или на уровне базы?

Comment: На уровне базы быстрее, но сложнее поддерживать

Comment: Смотря для чего это вам нужно и в каких объемах. Сам алгоритм расчета несложный, но если оно вам потребуется в расчетах в самой БД, то удобнее его там считать, хранить и передавать.

Answer (score 2):

Рекомендую использовать in-memory database или прилолжение в качестве cli, желательно писать его не на php

https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html

Answer (score 0):

Расчёт в БД будет происходить быстрее, чем на уровне приложения